# spamModerationLevel in Google java api

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

So I'm lookign into ways to edit some of less visible setting s on a google group, in specific the one found in:

Access Settings > Settings > Moderation > Spam Messages

This setting is what I believe is spamModerationLevel in the Group settings api.

I've tested changing other settings with the same code sucesfully, but that particular attribute does not change.

This works:

```
DirectoryUtils client = new DirectoryUtils(); //class with my google api methods
Directory directory = client.getDirectory(); //directory instance

Group group = client.retrieveGroup(directory, "api-test"); //api-test being the group I'm testing with

group.set("name", "Testing name change");    
Group modified = directory.groups().update(group.getEmail(), group).execute();
```

With that my group name changes with no problems. For testing the set() method I didnt use the api's setName() which does the same but now I know set() works. Now if i try this:

```
group.set("spamModerationLevel", "ALLOW");
Group modified = directory.groups().update(group.getEmail(), group).execute();
```

The group stays the same with no change to the settings I was looking to change.

I've noticed during debugging, the "group" variable has an added spamModerationLevel attribute after the set() command but when execute() returns teh group as "modified", it looks the same as "group" before the change.

Is there a way to do this change through the API that I'm missing?

Thanks,
Stephen